# Why is the class keyword used in this code?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, keyword

[The following is a part of a C++ example parser for simple arithmetic using the Composite pattern.](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~hxt/2013/c-programming-language/ParserTreeOO.cpp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// abstract base class E
class E {
public:
    // pure virtual member function
    // = 0  means no implementation, only type
    virtual int eval() = 0;
    // virtual destructor
    virtual ~E();
};

// derived class for plus tree nodes

class plus : public E {
    class E *e1;
    class E *e2;
public:
    plus(class E *e1, class E * e2)
    {
        this->e1 = e1;
        this->e2 = e2;
    }
    ~plus();
    int eval();
};
```

I don't understand what the `plus(class E *e1, class E * e2)` does. If E is a class, then surely it does not need to be prefixed with the `class` keyword, which in my understanding is only used for defining new classes? Why is the class keyword used in a function parameter?

Furthermore, when I delete the `class` keywords so as to result in the following class definition:

```
class plus : public E {
    E *e1;
    E *e2;
public:
    plus(E *e1, E * e2)
    {
        this->e1 = e1;
        this->e2 = e2;
    }
    ~plus();
    int eval();
};
```

The code (I mean the entire code with all of the seemingly unnecessary occurrences of the `class` keyword removed, not just the snippet I provided here) still compiles and builds and runs, seemingly normally. What's the reasoning for the use of the `class` keyword here?

Comment: Yeah, C++ allows the use of the `class` keyword even when you're just using the class, not defining it. As for why they did it here (inconsistently): No idea.

Comment: If it helps, in C, you *have* to use `struct` before using a structure. Like `class`, it is optional in C++ (most of the time).